# Minimum PHP/Server Requirements for Yii 2

Tags: php, ffmpeg, server, yii2

I tried to run my yii2 app on my web hosting (It has PHP5.4 and Linux Server). But when I tried to upload files then it showed me error that Fileinfo extension is not installed. I asked the server guys and they told me that they can not enable that extension because it is a shared hosting.

I tried the same app on some other hosting. I received this error:

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/ffmpeg.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/ffmpeg.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I want to know, what are the minimum server requirements (or required PHP extensions) for Yii2, so that I can find another host according to that.

Comment: what do you want to do, may be there are alternatives. Also note that Minimum reqirement are as dictated in framework's requirement.php
See http://www.sitepoint.com/expect-yii-2-0/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any shared hosting services that allow the use of ffmpeg - it's very heavy on CPU/RAM usage. You'll almost certainly need a dedicated/VPS, which as a bonus will allow you to install whatever you want.

Comment: Hi this helped me https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/requirements/requirements.php

Comment: But my hosting provider refused to give me fileinfo extension.

Comment: @FutureKing So you need a new hosting provider. I'm saying you likely won't find any shared ones that give you ffmpeg.

Comment: Its ok if they are not giving FFMPEG. At least they should provide all the extensions required by Yii2. But I couldn't find anyone who provide all those extensions.

Comment: @FutureKing Frameworks like Yii/Laravel are simply not designed to be installed on shared hosting. You can get a VPS somewhere like Digital Ocean for $5/month these days.

Comment: WOW! I have never seen such kind of low cost VPS. I am from India. Here hosting companies like ZnetLive are providing VPS from $25. which is very high for me. Is there any Indian version/Indian alternative of Digital Ocean? Do they provide CPanel like control panel?

Comment: @FutureKing I'd advise not using control panels. I can't speak to Indian VPS hosts but you could use Digital Ocean (or maybe Amazon's Singapore datacenter, where a reserved micro instance will run you about $7/month).

Comment: Why I should not use any control panel. Control panel make many tasks easier and fast. I use Linux Virtual Machine as local server for Web development purpose. But I have installed Webmin to make controlling and managing it easier.

Comment: @FutureKing Control panels also make many tasks harder and slow - professional sysadmins tend to hate them. See http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3922/question-about-migrated-post-that-was-closed/3924#3924.